# Best way to cache a password in an Excel VBA function

Tags: web-services, security, excel, vba, passwords

I need to connect to some remote database through Excel (don't ask me why ^^'). We can't connect directly through ODBC, but I will query a webservice on another computer connected to the database.
The login/password to send will be sent through https from excel. The webservice then will connect to the database with those informations.
I don't want to ask the password each time the webservice will be queried, I need to cache it.
Is there a better way (I'm pretty sure there is) than to store in some kind of global variable ?

Comment: Do you want to ask for the password the first time... each time the workbook is opened? Does the password need to be unretrievable after the workbook is closed?

Comment: No, it would be asked the first time the user will launch a webservice query. Then it would be cached maybe until the person closed the Excel document

Comment: Oh, and since my code is in an .xla, maybe I should find a special way to clean it at the closure of the .xls document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you described, I think that a global variable is the best option.

However, if you want the password to "last longer." You could hash it, and store it in the workbook, registry, or anywhere else you like. Use `GetSetting` and `SaveSetting` if you want to follow the registry method.

Comment: I think I will limit myself to the global variable then. It is OK for the user to retype the password each time he closes the spreadsheet